# Upload cropped "croppie" image to server using Java PlayFramework 2.6

Tags: java, ajax, file-upload, playframework-2.6, croppie

I've googled for the past 2 days and still can't find a solution to this problem. I can upload fine using the input element with type attribute set to file. But I cannot upload the cropped image using [croppie](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/) to the server.

Here is my register.scala.html:

```html
@helper.form(action = routes.ProfilesController.upload, 'id -> "profileForm", 'class -> "", 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
@CSRF.formField

<div  class="col-6 col-md-3 pic-padding">


<div id="upload-demo" class="upload-demo pic-1 mx-auto d-block rounded">

</div>

<div class="pic-number" href="#">1</div>
<label for="upload-pic1" class="pic-control-bg">
  <img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/plus.png")" class="pic-control">
</label>

<input type="file" id="upload-pic1" name="pic1" class="upload-btn" accept="image/*">


<button type="button" class="upload-result">Result</button>

<script>
  Demo.init();

</script>

</div>
}
```

Here is my main.js:

```js
$('.upload-result').on('click', function (ev) {
  $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
    type: 'canvas',
    size: 'viewport'
  }).then(function (resp) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:9000/upload",
      type: "POST",
      data: {"image":resp},
      success: function (data) {
        alert(resp);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Here is my ProfilesController.java

```js
public Result upload() {
    File file = request().body().asRaw().asFile();
    return ok("File uploaded");
}
```

Here is a snippet from routes file:

```html
POST    /upload                     controllers.ProfilesController.upload()
```

The error i get with the above solution is:

[CompletionException: java.lang.NullPointerException]

Please help! This has been stressing me out for the past 2 days, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: In my main.js I changed resp to resp.toDataURL and i can upload now but the uploaded file is empty. Also, even before i send the request via AJAX i can see that outputting "resp" gives me the cropped image Base64 URL but when I output  "resp.toDataURL" i get undefined. Why is this?

Comment: I figured out in main.js i need to be sending the data URL in the data attribute. In that case, just having "resp" will give me the data URL, so basically this gives me a internal server error on the JAVA side with the below error message. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: ERROR MESSAGE:! @794hg40i9 - Internal server error, for (POST) [/upload] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[CompletionException: java.lang.NullPointerException]]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:251)
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:178)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:363)

Answer (score 0):

This is not fully solved, but i've progressed enough to produce a different problem. I ended up changing my ajax request in main.js to:

$.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:9000/upload",
      type: "POST",
      data: resp,
      success: function (data) {
        alert(resp);

Then I also changed the profilecontroller.java to

public Result upload() {

```
    String dataUrl = request().body().asText();
    System.out.println(dataUrl);

    return ok("Data URI Passed");
```

}

This gave me the Data URI from javascript and passed it to the JAVA code. Now I need to try and upload the image using the Data URI. If you know the answer to this then please contribute to this post.